# Proper handling of UIControlEventValueChanged events

Tags: ios, event-handling, uikit, race-condition, uiswitch

I have a [`UISwitch`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with its corresponding[`UIControlEventValueChanged`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779) event bound to a function `[- handleSwitch:]`.

**View controller**

```
- (IBAction)handleSwitch:(UISwitch *)sender
{
    static BOOL oldState;

    if (sender.on && !oldState) {
        NSLog(@"off => on");
    } else if (oldState && !sender.on) {
        NSLog(@"on => off");
    } else if (oldState && sender.on) {
        NSLog(@"Big bug source: on => on");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Big bug source: off => off");
    }
    oldState = sender.on;
}
```

The program works fine when I press the switch once every few seconds. However, as soon as I start spamming the switch, I start getting "big bug source".

It seems that `sender.on` is changed again to its old value before the `[- handleSwitch]` function is invoked.

1. Switch changes from `Off` to `On`
2. Event "value changed" is put in the queue
3. Switch changes from `On` to `Off`
4. `[- handleSwitch:]` is invoked in response to the "value changed" event message. However, since the switch already changed back to the `Off` state, it cannot detect that the switch was in the `On` state before, when the event was sent.
5. There is no second invocation of `[- handleSwitch]`. Somehow, the two "value changed" events got combined into a single one.

This leads to the following question:

- How is this case commonly handled? Is it really necessary to handle transitions from the `UISwitch`'s state into the same state manually?
- The framework is intelligent enough to combine the two switch transitions into a single event. Why is it not intelligent enough to detect the `On` => `On` and `Off` => `Off` cases and remove the event from the queue in these cases?
- Is it possible that the switch value changes *during* the `[- handleSwitch]` function? Or is the function invoked on the GUI thread, therefore, blocking the user interface while running?

  If it is possible that the value changes while being in the method, how can one cope with it? Since the method only gets a pointer to the `UISwitch` itself as an argument, it cannot get its value at the time of the event creation. Only the current value can be retrieved, which may have already changed.